# How to update a document in firebase firestore using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when i run the following code i get this error.

['FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but User has 1']

```
func saveLabel(uid: String, label: String){
  
    let userRef = db.collection("User").document(uid)
    
    userRef.updateData(["label": label]) { (error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("updated")
        }else{
            print("not updated")
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: I fixed it. uid was coming back nil for some reason but it works now

Answer (score 1):

This error almost certainly means that `uid` is empty.  You should log it to make sure.

Comment: you were right it was coming back nil,  i fixed it. Thanks

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, it's customary on Stack Overflow to upvote it and mark it as correct using the buttons to the left.